# Another report designer substring or IIf issue

Tags: acumatica

I have one data field on the report, the data sample like following:

"75,80,80,80,92"
"75,80,80,80,93"
"75"
"75,80"

I created another expression field to try retrieved only third pair digits if length =14, so I have

```
=IIf(Len([CRCase.dtcase_Attributes])=14, Substring(Replace([CRCase.dtCase_Attributes],',',''), 4,2),'empty')
```

when I run the report, I could get "80" for first two rows, but error for bottom two. Is there any way to workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I figured out is using padright to make the strings having same length.

But still wondering why first part of boolean expression did not return false for short string.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem. The true portion of IIf is evaluating for all records, regardless of whether or not they meet the condition. It doesn't do anything with the true value for records that don't meet the condition, but it still tries to evaluate it which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's as Tim mentioned.  The full formula is evaluated to parse down the results.
In other words it's using this
1) Evaluate True method
2) Evaluate False method
3) Evaluate comparison
4) Show True/False by comparison.

In your case it's being resulted down to:

```
IIF(true,{substringvalue},{skipped}) for the first two rows and
IIF(false,ERROR,'empty') for the rest.
```

Because of the "ERROR" that occurs when trying to evaluate the true portion, the entire formula fails.

Padding is one solution here.

Make sure though to account for a null.  you can't pad right a null value.